# Windows azure price calculation and estimation (for mobile)

Tags: .net, azure, mobile

I'm really sorry to ask this but I don't find the correct answer in resources I found.
What is the easiest way to calculate the price and the needs (mobile services, cloud services, VM, etc...). To do a simple POC of a windows mobile app, with all the orchestration (using SignalR, maps, DB, etc....),
Thanks a lot and best regards,

N.

Comment: This really isn't something that can be answered here, as it's not a programming question (and there are many moving parts that would need to be defined, tier/size and quantity of each, etc). Azure has pricing calculators for all available services, and you'd be the best person to know what services your app would be using, and tally up rough cost estimates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but to help me, what are the mandatory blocksof azure needed to create a mobile Real-Time application ?

Comment: There *are* no "mandatory blocks." Lots of ways to implement this, with different subsets of Azure's features. It's wide-open to interpretation based on some items you tossed out ("SignalR, maps, DB, etc"). And now, in your comment, you threw in "real time" (which is also up for interpretation). That's the problem with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the team of Windows Azure does an excellent job and they give answer to all questions. With a professionalism that is really enjoyable.